# TranslateAnimation resetting views occasionally

Tags: android-animation

I am busy developing my first android app which is essentially a bubble burst type of game.
So far everything works except when I want to update a text box with a score.
Views are moved using translateanimation and all works as expected as long as a simple .setText() is not used.
When this is added occasionally some views that have been moved around previously suddenly move back to their original position. Additionally some variables also are set back to their original value.
I have tried updating the score via asyntask as well as runonuithread but the same issue occurs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out.
I had the text box which I use for the score in a seperate xml and in that xml I had a include statement pointing to another xml file which had all the controls which are used as bubbles/blocks.
By including the score text box in the same xml the issue was sorted out.
There must be some rules that Android has regarding animating/updating controls across two seperate layouts.